# Adding javascript to hyperlink

Tags: javascript

How can i add a Javascript alert to the hyperlink ?
I want to make the alert pop up when someone click on the link .
This is the script for now -

```
<a href="<?php echo ($link1);?>" onclick="popitup();" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" > Send </a>
```

And i want to add this to the link

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('Text.');</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define the `popitup()` function that you are calling in your `onclick` attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popitup() {
        alert('Text.');
    }
</script>
```

also if you want to prevent the link from redirecting under certain conditions you could return false from this handler:

```
<a href="<?php echo ($link1);?>" onclick="return popitup();" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true"> Send </a>
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popitup() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?')) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

if the alert should do some kind of logic you can use the return function like this

```
<a href="newlink.html" onClick="return confirm('do you really wanna go to this link?')" >the link</a>
```

or just add the alert w/o any logic in this way

```
<a href="newlink.html" onClick="alert('you are going to the link! beware!')" >the link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`<a href="new.html" onclick="alert('This is going to link')"> link </a>`

Comment: Darin's solution is probably better though as writing javascript in-line is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript statements to a href attribute by putting javascript: before the statement, so it would be something like:

```
<a href="javascript: alert('Text.');" ></a>
```